# how to implement lastIndexOf(array, value, [fromIndex]) function in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

lastIndexOf_.lastIndexOf(array, value, [fromIndex]) 
Returns the index of the last occurrence of value in the array, or -1 if value is not present. Pass fromIndex to start your search at a given index.

_.lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2);
=> 4

my code is:

```js
function lastIndexOf(array,value){
 
 var temp=[];
 for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(array[i]==value){
   return i;
  }
        return -1;
 }
 
}

console.log(lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],2));
```

Comment: Why did you tag `underscore.js`?

Comment: this is underscore.js function

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#lastIndexOf

Comment: It is not clear what you really want. You want us to debug the code?

Comment: yes,i want debug the code

Comment: Then I would suggest you use a debugger.

Comment: To add to @FrédéricHamidi's comment, Chrome and Firefox both have built-in debuggers, so you can find what errors your code is causing.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the standart Javascript function `lastIndexOf` which is working fine with arrays?

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3].lastIndexOf(2)
```

results

```
4
```

why should you invent the hot water again ?

EDIT:

made this edit for the 'inventors' to not invent again the decremental loops

```
function lastIndexOf(array,value) {

    for(var i=array.length;i>0;i--){
      if(array[i]==value) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: i inventing function lastIndexOf not using.

Comment: @AmitModi Probably for backwards compatibility since the never ending IE8 [does not support most Array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) that we take for granted.

Comment: ok, for the inventors I've made an edit and put a working code for the newly invented lastIndexOf :)

Comment: Nope, sorry, you also got it wrong. Interesting how such a simple question can be so easy to botch. (For what it's worth, you also didn't implement the optional `fromIndex` argument.)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - I'm not an wishing well and it is not wrong ... you think it is a problem to inplement fromIndex??? you are funny :) let the guy do something hisown for his home work ... don't worry about my skills :)

Comment: @Reflective, you say *let the guy do something his own for his homework*, but you're the one trying to spoon-feed them a solution, not me. And I can be pretty funny sometimes, yes, but array indices start at `0` in Javascript nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [ECMA-262 5.1 Edition/June 2011](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf), Page 133-134, Chapter **15.4.4.15 Array.prototype.lastIndexOf ( searchElement [ , fromIndex ] )**. Own comments are indicated.

```js
function lastIndexOf(O, searchElement, fromIndex) {
    var len, n, k, kPresent, elementK;
    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
    // ninascholz: given as parameter
    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument "length".
    // ninascholz: given as parameter
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    len = O.length;
    // 4. If len is 0, return -1.
    if (len === 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    // 5. If argument fromIndex was passed let n be ToInteger(fromIndex); else let n be len-1.
    n = parseInt(fromIndex) || len - 1;
    // 6. If n = 0, then let k be min(n, len – 1).
    // ninascholz: should read n >= 0, otherwise the else condition would be wrong
    if (n >= 0) {
        k = Math.min(n, len - 1);
    } else {
        // 7. Else, n < 0
        // a. Let k be len - abs(n).
        k = len - Math.abs(n);
    }
    // 8. Repeat, while k= 0
    while (k >= 0) {
        // a. Let kPresent be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of O with argument ToString(k).
        kPresent = k in O;
        // b. If kPresent is true, then
        if (kPresent) {
            // i. Let elementK be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with the argument ToString(k).
            elementK = O[k];
            // ii. Let same be the result of applying the Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm to searchElement and elementK.
            if (searchElement === elementK) {
                // iii. If same is true, return k.
                return k;
            }
        }
        // c. Decrease k by 1.
        k--;
    }
    // 9. Return -1.
    return -1;
}

function out(s) { var n = document.createElement('div'); n.innerHTML = s + '<br>'; document.getElementById('out').appendChild(n); }

// 4. If len is 0, return -1.
out(lastIndexOf([], 'e', -2)); // -1
out([].lastIndexOf('e', -2)); // -1

// 6. If n = 0, then let k be min(n, len – 1).
out(lastIndexOf(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'c', 10)); // 4
out(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].lastIndexOf('c', 10)); // 4

// 7. Else, n < 0
out(lastIndexOf(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'e', -2)); // -1
out(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].lastIndexOf('e', -2)); // -1

out(lastIndexOf(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'e', -1)); // 4
out(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].lastIndexOf('e', -1)); // 4

// ii. Let same be the result of applying the Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm to searchElement and elementK.
out(lastIndexOf([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], '5')); // -1
out([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].lastIndexOf('5')); // -1

out(lastIndexOf(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'e', 2)); // -1
out(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].lastIndexOf('e', 2)); // -1

// iii. If same is true, return k.
out(lastIndexOf(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'e')); // 4
out(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].lastIndexOf('e')); // 4
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

First off, reverse the for loop.

Second, the lastIndex doesn't make sense, are you looking from that spot backwards?  if it is, it would be pretty easy to implement.  Just look from that spot as the start of i.

```js
function lastIndexOf(array,value){
 
 var temp=[];
 for(var i=array.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  if(array[i]==value){
   return i;
  }
 }
    return -1;
}

console.log(lastIndexOf([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],2));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function lastIndexOf(array,value){

  var temp;
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      if(array[i]==value){
          temp = i;
      }
  }
  if (temp) return temp;
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't. The answerer didn't bother to test it, and obviously neither did you.